# How can I loop through a list and get the first two index items on the same line

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop

```
ourList = [
    'Polly Ester', '549-5393', 'Bud Wieser', '(218) 477-3928', 'Jack Hammer',
    '277-4829', 'Mike Rafone', '345-3453', 'Bill Ding',  '218-473-4373',
    'Earl Lee Riser', '701-304-8293', 'Tim Burr', '(612) 593-2629', 'Bud',
     '(701) 487-8532'
]
def writeFile(filename, phonebook):
    file = open(filename, 'w+')
    print('your information is being written in', filename)
    stringedList = ', '.join(phonebook)
    file.write(stringedList)

def readFile(filename):

  phonebook = []
  file = open(filename, "r")

  for aline in file:
    person = aline.split(",")

    if person[1][-1] == '/n':
      pn = person.pop(1)
      person.append(pn[:-1])

    phonebook.append(person)

  file.close()

  return phonebook

print(readFile("phone.txt"))

readFile('phone.txt')

choices = ['exit', 'search phonebook', 'add entry', 'delete entry', 'print phonebook']

def printEnteries(phonebook) :

  person = phonebook
  print(person)
  print("Name                         Phone")
  print("--------------------         --------------")
  for word in person:
    index = 0
    print(word[index])
    index += 1
    print(word[index])


def main ():
    
  def menu(choices):
    for (i, item) in enumerate(choices,start=0):
      print(i, item)

    userInput = input('choice?: ')
    print(userInput)
    return userInput

  choices = ['exit', 'search phonebook', 'add entry', 'delete entry', 'print phonebook']

  phonebook = readFile("phone.txt") 

  option = menu(choices)


  while option !=0:
    if option == 1:
      print("search phonebook")
    elif option == 2:
      print("add entry")
    elif option == 3:
      print("delete entry")
    elif option == 4:
      print(printEntries(phonebook))
    else:
        print('not an option')

    option = menu(choices)

  writeFile("phone02.txt", phonebook)

main()
```

the problem am having with this is that the main function's while loop returns a "not an option". I get the user's input, pass it down to the options variable and I use that in the while loop. From the print(userInput) inside the (menu) function, it clearly returns an integer so why doesn't the while loop work execute properly?

Comment: I think it's returning a string. try casting it to an integer

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your posted code fails because you depend on a file we don't have.  Unless you have isolated the trouble to the file input, replace the file reading with the resulting data structure.  You posted about 75 lines of code for what seems to be a much smaller problem with loop control.  I doubt that many people will try to visually verify such a large block of code.

Comment: if you check new line then it has to be `\n` instead of `/n`. But it is simple to remove it with `aline.strip().split(",")`

Comment: `input()` always gives string - even if user put some number. You have to compare with strings `option == "1"` or you have to convert to integer - `option = int(option)`

Comment: Can you just simply mention clearly what is your input and what's the output you need?